# catkin run_tests with stdout output of rostest

Tags: ros, rostest, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rostest by adding `add_rostest` in CMakelists.txt, and catkin_tools to build it.
I know how to test specific package with `catkin run_tests pkg --no-deps`, but no idea to write the test's stdout to the screen like `rostest --text hoge.test`.

Anyone who know about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218993/catkin-run_tests-with-stdout-output-of-rostest/) by [wkentaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20444/wkentaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2015-10-12

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though you've probably figured this out already, you can `catkin_test_results` for that these days.
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/run_tests.html

UPDATE 20180529 For `catkin_tools`, passing workspace folder path to `catkin_test_results` works. Some examples:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_test_results
```

Or

```
catkin_test_results --verbose ~/catkin_ws
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2018-05-29**:
The question was about catkin tools, the link you provided is about catkin_make. I tired but there is no test_results folder after running catkin run_tests or catkin test

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-05-29**:
@Mehdi. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my post.